# .htaccess redirect with condition

Tags: .htaccess

here is my rules for htaccess file.

```
RewriteRule ^admin/?$ admin/index.php
RewriteRule ^cart/([0-9]+)/?$ cart.php?t=$1
RewriteRule ^register$ register.php
RewriteRule ^login$ login.php
RewriteRule ^forgot-password$ forgot_password.php
RewriteRule ^terms-and-conditions$ terms_and_conditions.php
RewriteRule ^request-consideration$ request_consideration.php

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ products.php?cid=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ products.php?cid=$1&scid=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ product_details.php?cid=$1&scid=$2&id=$3

ErrorDocument 404 /error_404.php

Now the problem is when i try to redirect it say www.example.com/cart/123 it goes products.php page. I want to restrict the url www.example.com/cart/123 only. so www.example.com/cart or www.example.com/cart/abc will redirect to error_404 page. same for other also like register, login etc.
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: on this current configuration, if i modify the url like /cart or cart/abc its going to products.php page. but its working fine with /cart/123. But I want if someone modify the url like /cart or /cart/abc it should go to error_404 page as only number is permitted with /cart.

Comment: You have multiple rules of the same pattern. So the first is always served first. This is a normal behaviour of mod-rewrite.

Comment: Then how to achieve this. I mean is there any condition to satisfy my requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on you comments, you want to redirect the uri to 404 page if **/cart** or **/cart/abc** is requested, you can use the following rules. Put this at the top of your htaccess before other RewriteRules

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^cart/?$ - [R=404,L]
RewriteRule ^cart/[A-Za-z]+/?$ - [R=404,L]
```

Comment: thanks starkeen. thanks for your kind reply. It works.